# How To Make Contenteditable Draggable and Resizable in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

There is any way to make content editable to be drag-gable & Re-sizable without Plugin or with plugin in VueJs?
I will appreciate any views-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Vue-Draggable`, you can check out their github page [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), see a demo [here](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/simple).

Comment: it is  work but it doesn't render/support content-editor